Something above
What object connects them? The answer is a 6-letter word.



There was an edit that did two things: (1) replaced the image with a larger version and (2) changed the number of boxes next to the topmost item. @Prim3numbah, can you confirm that you intended both of those changes?

@GarethMcCaughan It's solved now ofc, but yeah only (2) was intentional

The mystery object is a...

 ...SPHERE

Because each of these images leads us to...

 ...a connection with a specific layer in Earth's atmosphere (as the title says: 'something above' us, quite literally!).

Starting from the bottom...

 The bottommost symbol is the Greek letter delta. In mathematics, this letter is used to represent a change in the value of a variable (in calculus). The prefix TROPO- can be used to mean 'change'. Note that 'TROPO' is a 5-letter prefix, matching the number of empty boxes to the side of this symbol.

 Proceeding upwards, the next symbol shows layers, or 'strata', providing us with the next level of our atmosphere: the STRATOsphere (6 letters, again matching the boxes).

 We next see a symbol highlighting in red the middle of an object. The prefix MESO- means 'middle', and - you guessed it - the MESOsphere is the next level of Earth's atmosphere we encounter.

 Above that, the 6-letter prefix THERMOsphere is represented by a heat symbol...

 ...then our 3-letter tier is satisfied by the EXOsphere, clued by the red-highlighted external component of the symbol.

Finally, above the dividing line we see an image representing...

 ...air or the 4-letter (4 boxes) prefix ATMO. This completes the fact we are looking at the ATMOSPHERE overall, and all of our components are connected by the word SPHERE!


Source: noaa.gov


Thats indeed the object :) Well done!
